# Update in multiview using Linq

Tags: asp.net, linq, multiview

I want to update details using linq to entities. But instead of takin a new aspx page i want to update details in another view. will it work.? and please give the linq to entity update query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume:

1. `db` is the context of your Database Entity.
2. `Table_name` is the name of Table you need to update.
3. `row_id` is the value you are using to search for the data in the Table.

To update using linq you need to fetch the record first using the below query:

```
var data = (from r in db.Table_name
            where r.id == row_id
            select r).FirstOrDefault();
```

Now to update the values just update them. For example:

```
data.Name = "Firstname lastname"
data.IsActive = true;
.
.
```

and so on

After you have updated the values in `data` you need to Save the changes made by you by this command:

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

That's it.

Comment: thank you. but will this work on multiview or i need create a new aspx page..??

Comment: Yes it should work. You need to select the correct `DataSource` in your view though.